# Why Immutable Map Order Changed When Any Keys Deleted?

Tags: reactjs, redux, immutable.js

I have an issue when using Immutable JS with Redux on my React application. Here is the sample code that I created:

```
const entry1 = {id: 1, name: 'Entry 1'}
const entry2 = {id: 2, name: 'Entry 2'}
const entry3 = {id: 3, name: 'Entry 3'}
const entry4 = {id: 4, name: 'Entry 4'}
const entry5 = {id: 5, name: 'Entry 5'}

const entries = Immutable.Map({1: entry1, 2: entry2, 3: entry3, 4: entry4, 5: entry5})
const updatedEntries = entries.delete('3')

// First Console Log
console.log(entries.valueSeq().toJS())

// Second Console Log
console.log(updatedEntries.valueSeq().toJS())
```

In my first console log, the order is correct: 1,2,3,4,5. But in my second console log the order is messed, it become: 1,2,5,4.

Any idea what's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Map` does not guarantee order. If you want to keep it in the same order you should use [`OrderedMap`](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/OrderedMap)

> **OrderedMap**
>
> A type of Map that has the additional guarantee that the iteration order of entries will be the order in which they were set()

Comment: It works thank you for your help, It also good to mention that if we use merge in OrderedMap, we must use toOrderedMap() to make sure the output is not converted to Map.

Comment: @mario they don't say anything about that [in the docs](https://immutable-js.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/OrderedMap/merge), are you sure it is needed?